# What happens to @user in new and create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I was reading [this article about new, create, and forms](https://www.launchacademy.com/codecabulary/learn-rails/writing-forms) and there are a few parts on User creation process that I don't fully understand.

I want to create User with basic attributes: `name`, `email`. On routes I have `resources :user`, and:

```
users_controller.rb

def new
    @user = User.new
end

def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
        redirect_to @user, alert: "User created successfully."
    else
        redirect_to new_user_path, alert: "Error creating user."
    end
end


views/users/new.html.erb

<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>

    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
    ...
```

on `new` instance variable `@user` is created: `@user = User.new`. Now, I understand that this `new` `@user` is the same `@user` used in `<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>`(right?). I don't understand *when* `@user` in `create` method comes in.

There is no `create.html.erb` because create is really a POST request. Does that mean `@user` on `create` gets passed on from `new`'s `@user`? When does `create` method gets activated? Why do I need to declare `@user = User.new` in *both* `new` and `create`? When does `create`'s `@user` gets saved (in other word, what action saves this new user instance)?

I apologize for the many questions. There are a lot of behind-the-scenes that I don't know. If I have to sum it up, what I want to understand is:

How does `form_for` work with `new` and `create` to create user and what does `form_for` do with each `new`'s`@user` and `create`'s `@user`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails copies controller instance variables to whatever view is rendered: when the `new` view is rendered, the `@user` variable has the same value as `@user` in the controller.

The `create` method is called when the form is submitted (when the user clicks submit). It creates a new instance of `User`, using the submitted parameters. Every http request is processed by a new instance of the appropriate controller, so this `@user` is unrelated to the instance from the new action.  Nothing happens in terms of the database until the call to `@user.save`

Comment: `@user.save` is called after the "Submit" button in the form is "clicked", right? (is @user.save triggered by the submit button?)

Comment: Clicking submit makes the browser send the request that calls the create action. This calls `user.save`

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. when you `POST` to the user route, it re-renders the `new` method, unless you redirect or render another method. So declaring the instance variable `@user` in the create method allows this to be passed back to the `new` template. If you didn't specify this instance variable, Rails would complain that the form param can't be blank since `@user` isn't set (Since the method rendering the template is `create` not `new`).